# Why was this non-spam recommendation answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, not-an-answer

After spending quite some time looking for a Visual Studio extension solving a problem, I posted it as an answer to save time for my fellow developers who end up on the same Stack Overflow question as I did. However two moderators decided that my answer was not good enough and just decided to delete it.

My answer is 100% helping whoever will find this question.

Do you believe it's acceptable that moderators can decide that a non-spam answer should be deleted?

[image: Answer that was deleted]

Original question for context: [Can I create a file that sits next to a .Designer.cs file in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223249/can-i-create-a-file-that-sits-next-to-a-designer-cs-file-in-visual-studio)

Comment: You need to add some content around the link, explaining how to use that extension...

Comment: @paper1111 What content do you want me to add? A screenshot? I'm not writing an encyclopedia, just posting something that will 100% help people looking for it.

Comment: The first comment in the answer explains it all, demonstrate how it solves the problem

Comment: Post was reported in SO Botics: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/111347?m=38920418#38920418

Comment: "Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate how it solves the problem in the answer itself"

Comment: In the process 2 other link only answers were deleted as well: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxjhA.png

Comment: @rene The 2 other deletes were pointing to a dead website and a dead extension. No complain form me about these deletions.

Comment: Parfait is not a moderator, just a member of the community who has earned the right to cast delete votes; it would have taken another 4 community-member votes to delete without moderator help. The moderator acted on the Very Low Quality flag cast on the answer. If the link went dead, anyone looking for an answer would hardly be the wiser. **How** would you use that extension, how does it solve the problem? The moderator didn't just delete the answer, it was converted to a comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: @gnat not dupe, this is not about NAA flags

Comment: @MartijnPieters If the link went dead, they could not download the extension. Adding more text to my answer would not help them to use an extension they can't download.

Comment: @John: consider this: if there was enough of a description of how the plugin works, I could find an alternative if the plugin ever was deleted. With just a name, I have next to nothing.

Comment: Hmya, extensions provided by Mads Kristensen are always a good way to solve a problem.  But the simple bots that SO users create do not know this, and I doubt their creators know this.  He's only famous in a small circle of programmers and review is done by people that don't have to know anything about the [tags] on the question.  Review sucks pretty heavily that way.  You have to beef-up your answer to ward them off.  If you don't want to take the time then consider that your comment on the accepted answer is good enough as-is.

Comment: Context is everything, @Hans. There is 0 context here.

Comment: @Martijn - the question has tags, they provide is the context to users that want to solve the same problem.  A typical response would be "Ah, Mads my man, saving my buns again".  But you don't know anything about the tags and thus can't judge the context or the value of the answer.  Consider that this might be your problem and not the answer's problem.  Writing answers so they are clear to *everybody* is unrealistic and unnecessary.

Comment: @HansPassant: so is expecting only the experts in a tag to keep their tag clean. That's why we have certain guidelines, to make sure that most community moderation can be done without having to rely on a much smaller subset.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If the answer is not good enough for most people, less people would vote for it and it stays at the bottom. For me that is self-moderating. I dont think the answer was worth deleting.

Answer (score 19):

Posting an answer that links to a tool/plug-in always runs the risk for being considered an off-site recommendation or even spam. Maybe for questions that can only be answered with a link to a plugin or tool this might work but today those questions would most likely be closed anyway.

If you don't want your link only answer to be deleted it is up to you to provide enough context so the answer isn't just *hey, here is a plugin that does what you want [link]*.

You could provide a screenshot of its usage, instructions how to use the plugin, caveats or other peculiarities when using the plugin, etc. And then still the answer keeps its real value until the link goes dead ...

Without that the answer is considered barely useful and therefor either flagged for deletion or converted to a comment to not loose its value.